# how to create app which can view larger than iphone screen

Tags: iphone

i create a new InputData.xib which has few text box which actually larger than iphone screen, but when i exe the app, text box which in beyond the iphone screen is hidden and i unable to scroll the screen, how this can resolve,

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the iPhone screen has a window that is of fixed size and position.  All scrolling needs to be done with `UIScrollView` objects.  `UITextView` is a subclass that works well for text.  `UITableView` is for lists, like in the iPod app.  `UIScrollView` itself can be used for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a UITextView, rather than a UITextField. Make its bounds equal to the screen bounds; if there's more content than will fit, it will handle scrolling within it automatically.